# Update text mark on hovering different marks in Vega

Tags: hover, vega-lite, vega

In my Vega specification I have 3 marks: a bar, a text related to that bar, and a text ("Hovered EventType details mark") that is supposed to plot the corresponding details when a particular bar / related text is hovered.

I never managed to make this work.

This is the current Vega specification:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "description": "The PM2.5 value of Beijing observed 15 keys, highlighting the keys when PM2.5 level is hazardous to human health. Data source https://chartaccent.github.io/chartaccent.html",
  "background": "white",
  "padding": 5,
  "height": 250,
  "width": 500,
  "autosize": {
    "type": "fit",
    "resize": true
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "source",
      "values": [
        { "key": "TYPE 1", "doc_count": 113 },
        { "key": "TYPE 2", "doc_count": 32 }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "signals": [
    {
      "name": "hoveredBar",
      "value": null,
      "on": [
        {"events": "rect:mouseover", "update": "datum.key"},
        {"events": "rect:mouseout", "update": "null"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "hoveredText",
      "value": null,
      "on": [
        {"events": "text:mouseover", "update": "datum.key"},
        {"events": "text:mouseout", "update": "null"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "hoveredEventType",
      "value": null,
      "on": [
        {"events": "rect:mouseover", "update": "datum"},
        {"events": "rect:mouseout", "update": "null"},
        {"events": "text:mouseover", "update": "datum"},
        {"events": "text:mouseout", "update": "null"}
      ]
    }
  ],
  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "x",
      "type": "band",
      "domain": {"data": "source", "field": "key"},
      "range": "width",
      "paddingInner": 0.1,
      "paddingOuter": 0.2
    },
    {
      "name": "y",
      "type": "linear",
      "domain": {"data": "source", "field": "doc_count"},
      "range": "height",
      "nice": true
    }
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "rect",
      "from": {"data": "source"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "x": {"scale": "x", "field": "key"},
          "width": {"scale": "x", "band": 0.8},
          "y": {"scale": "y", "field": "doc_count"},
          "y2": {"scale": "y", "value": 0},
          "fill": {"value": "#00afa4"},
          "opacity": {"value": 1}
        },
        "update": {
          "opacity": [
            {"test": "datum.key === hoveredBar || datum.key === hoveredText", "value": 0.7},
            {"value": 1}
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "from": {"data": "source"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "x": {"scale": "x", "field": "key", "band": 0.43},
          "y": {"scale": "y", "field": "doc_count", "offset": -10},
          "text": {"field": "key"},
          "align": {"value": "center"},
          "fill": {"value": "black"}
        },
        "update": {
          "fill": [
            {"test": "datum.key === hoveredBar || datum.key === hoveredText", "value": "#f05c3e"},
            {"value": "black"}
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    // Hovered EventType details mark
    {
      "type": "text",
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "x": {"signal": "width - 10"},
          "y": {"signal": "-150"},
          "text": {"signal": "hoveredEventType ? hoveredEventType.key + ': ' + hoveredEventType.doc_count : ''"},
          "align": {"value": "right"},
          "baseline": {"value": "bottom"},
          "fill": {"value": "#f05c3e"},
          "fontWeight": {"value": "bold"},
          "fontSize": {"value": 16}
        },
        "update": { 
          "fillOpacity": {"signal": "hoveredEventType ? 1 : 0"}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I am not sure if the signal "hoveredEventType", which is supposed to receive data during hover and mouseout events, is correctly defined, since it never gets to be triggered. In comparison, the other signals - "hoveredBar" and "hoveredText" - work as expected updating the bar / related text marks.

Is my approach wrong, or is there a limitation that prevents the behavior I intend to implement?

Comment: Please update your spec so it works in the editor. Can you clarify the requirement and problem?

Comment: Thanks for checking out, David. I have updated the specification. Basically, when hovering over the bars or text I want in the upper-right corner the corresponding "key" and "doc_count" value to be displayed.

Comment: I'll answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the following what you want?

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "description": "The PM2.5 value of Beijing observed 15 keys, highlighting the keys when PM2.5 level is hazardous to human health. Data source https://chartaccent.github.io/chartaccent.html",
  "background": "white",
  "padding": 5,
  "height": 250,
  "width": 500,
  "autosize": {"type": "fit", "resize": true},
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "source",
      "values": [
        {"key": "TYPE 1", "doc_count": 113},
        {"key": "TYPE 2", "doc_count": 32}
      ]
    }
  ],
  "signals": [
    {
      "name": "hoveredBar",
      "value": null,
      "on": [
        {"events": "rect:mouseover", "update": "datum.key"},
        {"events": "rect:mouseout", "update": "null"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "hoveredText",
      "value": null,
      "on": [
        {"events": "text:mouseover", "update": "datum.key"},
        {"events": "text:mouseout", "update": "null"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "hoveredEventType",
      "value": null,
      "on": [
        {"events": "rect:mouseover", "update": "datum"},
        {"events": "rect:mouseout", "update": "null"},
        {"events": "text:mouseover", "update": "datum"},
        {"events": "text:mouseout", "update": "null"}
      ]
    }
  ],
  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "x",
      "type": "band",
      "domain": {"data": "source", "field": "key"},
      "range": "width",
      "paddingInner": 0.1,
      "paddingOuter": 0.2
    },
    {
      "name": "y",
      "type": "linear",
      "domain": {"data": "source", "field": "doc_count"},
      "range": "height",
      "nice": true
    }
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "rect",
      "from": {"data": "source"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "x": {"scale": "x", "field": "key"},
          "width": {"scale": "x", "band": 0.8},
          "y": {"scale": "y", "field": "doc_count"},
          "y2": {"scale": "y", "value": 0},
          "fill": {"value": "#00afa4"},
          "opacity": {"value": 1}
        },
        "update": {
          "opacity": [
            {
              "test": "datum.key === hoveredBar || datum.key === hoveredText",
              "value": 0.7
            },
            {"value": 1}
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "from": {"data": "source"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "x": {"scale": "x", "field": "key", "band": 0.43},
          "y": {"scale": "y", "field": "doc_count", "offset": -10},
          "text": {"field": "key"},
          "align": {"value": "center"},
          "fill": {"value": "black"}
        },
        "update": {
          "fill": [
            {
              "test": "datum.key === hoveredBar || datum.key === hoveredText",
              "value": "#f05c3e"
            },
            {"value": "black"}
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "data": [{}],
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "x": {"signal": "width - 10"},
          "y": {"signal": "-150"},
          "text": {
            "signal": "hoveredEventType ? hoveredEventType.key + ': ' + hoveredEventType.doc_count : ''"
          },
          "align": {"value": "right"},
          "baseline": {"value": "bottom"},
          "fill": {"value": "#f05c3e"},
          "fontWeight": {"value": "bold"},
          "fontSize": {"value": 16}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: It's exactly what I wanted, thank you. I was wondering if specifying the data source in the mark would have made a difference, but I didn't know what value should I chose.